# Jquery add variable to another variable name dynamically

Tags: jquery, variables, dynamic

I define three variables (just for example) as follows:

```
window.myCirclePlayer_0 = ...
window.myCirclePlayer_1 = ...
window.myCirclePlayer_2 = ...
```

Somewhere else in my code (pseu-code):

```
var index = 0 1 or 2; //index can be 0, 1 or 2, we don't know which yet
```

I then want to add the index to the window variable so it calls the correct method. This doesn't work though. Is something like this even possible?

```
window.myCirclePlayer_[index].doMethod();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `window['myCirclePlayer_' + index].doMethod()` but you should consider another approach. When you see variables like `foo_1` and `foo_2` you should probably be using an array.

Than way you can do something like:

```
var circlePlayers = [
  ...,
  ...,
  ...
];
```

Then you can use the index more naturally like:

```
circlePlayers[index].doMethod();
```

You can also add more `circlePlayers` like:

```
circlePlayers.push(...);
```

I only used `...` in the code examples above because that's what you used.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you.